# error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to change my git mergetool kdiff3 to p4merge. because I'm getting an error on my windows system using kdiff3 mergetool.

> /mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 128: C:\Program
>   Files\KDiff3\kdiff3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
>   application/config/constants.php seems unchanged.

So that I want to change to kdiff3 to p4merge, Here also I'm getting an error like

> warning: merge.tool has multiple values error: cannot overwrite
>   multiple values with a single value
>          Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change merge.tool.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Either kdiff3 or p4merge

Comment: post as text, not a screenshot

Comment: Sure @avigil For better understand I post

Comment: Look into your config file and make sure that there is no duplicated setting for the merge tool (two or more rows for `merge.tool`): `git config --global --edit`

Comment: If you do not see a duplicated config row you could use `git config --list` to list all settings in all config files (local, global, system) and edit those config files to remove duplicated entries

Comment: Yes! it has duplicate values

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri, remove the duplicate values and then try adding the `p4merge` and update with the feedback if it works or not

Comment: I have removed Duplicate lines. Still I'm getting " /mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 128: p4merge.exe: command not found
readme.rst seems unchanged. "

Comment: I removed Kdiff3 @TarunLalwani

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat ~/.gitconfig` to your question?

Comment: Here @TarunLalwani  https://i.imgur.com/svEj7zA.png previously I have kdiff3 also. I removed Kdiff3.

Comment: Can you make sure you either use path like `C:\\xyz\\abc` or `C:/xyz/abc`. Fix the path and then try again @siddharthaesunuri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170846/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-siddhartha-esunuri).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible your kdiff3 installation is broken since it is not working. Or maybe you tried to edit config file manually and messed its content. why? Because windows executables have `.exe` extension in general. you may try editing config again.

Anyways, that is not important anymore. This is what you need to use if you want to try any other tool.

```
git mergetool --tool=p4merge
```

There are possibly others already installed with your git. You can see all of them in addition to compatible others.

```
git mergetool --tool-help
```

Edit:
This command works only if you set your path to the tool correctly. Otherwise, you always get `No files need merging` result. You already know how to set the path, but I will include here for anyone else that might need.

Get the list of configuration items:

```
git config -l
```

See if you already have values set correctly, if any. then set to correct value or remove.

```
git config --unset mergetool.p4merge.path
git config --add mergetool.p4merge.path "c:/somewhere/p4merge.exe"
```

---

EDIT:
I will offer a cleaning process so, these additional commands will help.

first steps are to make a backup of current settings. The simplest way is using these listings, then copy paste results.

```
git config --list
git config --global --list
```

then with these edit commands, just get config files' path and backup them (vim shows path) or save to a different location inside the editor.

```
git config --edit
git config --global --edit
```

now backups are ready, just exit editor. do not try to edit manually if it is not really needed.

```
git config --unset name
git config --global --unset name
git config --remove-section name
git config --global --remove-section name
```

`merge.tool`, `mergetool.name`, `diff.tool` and `difftool.name` are the ones to clean here. when you list the configs again, you should not see these names. local and global should be cleaned separately.

Then set back those we just cleaned one by one. but this time first try them on local configuration first then if successful set on global too.

```
git config merge.tool name
git config mergetool.name.property value
git config diff.tool name
git config difftool.name.property value
```

Here `property` is those like `cmd` and `path`, and `value` is their values which you can copy from your backups. Now the important thing here is to `set only 1 tool` at a time at first.

One last thing about paths. You (the OP) seem to use Linux-like environment, so using `/` instead of `\\` would make `path` and `cmd` better to understand.

Comment: git config --unset mergetool.p4merge.path this is not unset my value

Comment: After running this command also I'm getting same value after running git config -l

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri, from what I see in your config file you wrote in chat window, you define tools twice. they have their own names but this might be the source of the problem. will you please try deleting one of those `[mergetool "name"]` and `[difftool "name"]`? then let me know here

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri, I added a cleanup section to my answer. I advise to try it. it a bit painful to do but that should solve the problem

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri, may you please provide a feedback if your problem solved or not? giving an answer to a question is useless until the problem in the question gets solved.

Comment: I Re-installed git again. Now it's working fine. Before your answer I reinstalled. Same problem I facing my co-worker too. I will try this solution. I really appreciate your time. After I try I will approve your answer :)